# Is there any technique to give a metaball effect to the particles emitting from a UV Sphere?

Tags: particles

I have a UV Sphere emitter which emits sphere particles. As in the figure the emission is not organic. Is there any way to make it more organic like the particle is stretched out from the sphere like metaballs separate?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't really emit particles directly from *Meta Objects* themselves, so you'll just have to fake it.
Just add a large Metaball overlapping your real UV sphere covering the actual emitter.

Adjust its size so it covers it entirely, or alternatively make the real emitter non-renderable.

[image]

Make sure it is named after a similar prefix to the particle Metaball (`MBall##` by default), so they actually interact with each other.

[image]

---

This is beyond the scope of the original question, but by popular demand here are the settings for the first demo image, relevant properties circled.

Simple particle system with *Newtonian Physics*, pointing to a small Metaball object.
Under *Velocity* turn off *Normal* and increase *Object Z* slightly. In the *Field Weights* disable gravity so they "float up", then add a texture to it.

[image]

Make the texture is *Blend* type, and turn off all influences except *Size*. Switch *Mapping* to *Strand/Particle* so it maps out "through time" rather than any spatial coordinate. Under the *Color* panel enable the *Color Ramp* and flip the default result direction so they shrink with age rather than grow.

[image]

Comment: Man, this is great. But can you elaborate a bit more about the settings? Thanks

Comment: Just a simple particle system emitting small Metaballs. Gravity turned off, and a Z force puling them up. Only "fancy" thing is a texture affecting their size over time so they shrink as they go up

Comment: ok... we'll have to search a bit to reproduce that great effect so... will try to do ; )

Comment: @lemon Check it out, let me know if anything is unclear ;)

Comment: Duarte... will give a try tomorrow... a blend file would be time sparing... but we have to work too, to learn around this, so this is not a request... Thanks again, this answer should be one of the great ones.

Comment: I rarely even save my answer files, providing a ready made solution feels detrimental to learning, compared to recreating the steps yourself. It also seems beyond the scope of the original question, but it took all of five minutes to make from scratch, so I'm sure catch on quick :)

Comment: The whole texture system seems more 'legacy' than any other part of Blender.. I guess nodes will deal with it, so not worth special attention..

Comment: I've been aching for the legacy texture system to be replaced by node based solution, ideally compatible with Cycles/EEVEE nodes. One could then conjure up more complex setups or even match a displacement node with the material textures.

Comment: Thank You very much for the tips