# How to make complex connections across spheres

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have this mesh here, I'm making it for a game. My question is, how I can make every sphere connect to each other like the three center ones. I've tried so many ways already, but everytime the topology just makes it impossible.

[image]
[image]

([This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from) post doesn't resolve my problem)

Comment: you need to create holes in spheres: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGQgqlVq_Cg ... then create bridges between the spheres, have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use metaball objects instead of straight mesh objects, and you might consider looking into that.  Metaballs can be converted to meshes at any time you'd like with the "convert to" operation,

Comment: @bjorn HI. Please don't post the same question more than once. If the linked duplicate didn't help, you should edit your original question and state how you tried and why it didn't help. Editing will put it up for review so it can be reopen. Posting "*doesn't work*" without stating why, doesn't help us give you any other suggestion

Comment: Are the spheres at static positions and sizes? Or be anywhere, any sizes?

Comment: Moonboots
Thank you for your answer, your video actually helped and I almost finished my mesh. The only thing I'm struggling with is the top-right sphere. Any idea on how to do that?