# Assign metaballs to trails form a particle system

Tags: particles

currently switching from C4d to Blender, I try to reproduce some classic motion graphic effects in blender.

[image]

To illustrate my question, here's a link to watch (6min 45s): https://mattrunks.com/fr/formations/cinema-4d/eclaboussures-2d-x-particles

I am stuck when I want to assign metaballs to my trails. I could render my particles as object with a meta ball as reference, but the look will be some spheres and I want more a stroke look. Like this ...

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/194013#194013

Comment: Use type Capsule instead of Ball ... There you can specify length ... https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/structure.html

Comment: Thanks guys, great example from Duarte Farrajota Ramos, looks like I missed this capsule...

Comment: If you will be able to reproduce this effect by this way, please create answer, I m interested :) I'm quite skeptic about using meta object, since they have very low connectivity for such "elastic" effect presented in video. ... and please next time attach some screenshots instead of external links that are not permanent (this site is meant to be a knowledge base). Thank you

Comment: Yes you're right, I am not able to reproduce this elastic effect with the meta balls. Maybe I will check later with a cloth object, since I am new to Blender, I don't know if this approach would make sense. (Got it for the screen shot)

Answer (score 0):

In particle system you have render, select object and now your trail is rendering a specific object that you select

Comment: I didn t notice you could replace the trails by an object after caching them, thank you!