# How to get fluid to behave like droplets on a hydrophobic surface

Tags: fluid-simulation, force-fields, meta-objects

I am trying to create an animation of the scene shown in the picture below. I want all the little fluid droplets to be attracted to the big one in the middle and be absorbed by it. I have tried using fluid simulations for this but I can't get the fluid to act in the way that I want.

I have considered using metaballs also, but I couldn't really get them to deform properly on the ground be absorbed.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? I am using Blender 2.93.0 Alpha.

[image: BEAT.1000K (everyday 05.13.16) Art Print by beeple]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from

Comment: The question title does not seem to represent the question. Try “how to get fluid to behave like droplets on a hydrophobic surface.” But anyway, after resisting puns about not wanting to help create something evil, I notice that some of the drops are actually touching in the photograph, but are not merging together. Soft body physics, maybe? Or maybe sphere particles that are then booleaned from the floor and subsurfed to give a drippy appearance.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks for the help with the title and your suggestion. I thought of doing a soft body simulation as well but I actually do want the droplets to merge with each other, so I think the only option is a fluid sim. I am having trouble getting enough surface tention for the droplets to stay more or less spherical with Mantaflow though. I heard the Flip Fluids add-on does a better job with this so I might buy it and try that. Looking for something like these droplets I guess: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug0kQ3a8Ky0.

Comment: This is also something that get's close to what I want, it was made with Realflow though and that is somewhat out of my league and price range: https://vimeo.com/93212243

Comment: @Aeneas wait… isn’t mantaflow flip?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard If I understand it correctly the fluid simulation part of Mantaflow also uses the flip method but the Flip Fluids Add-on just has a different implementation.