# Controlling opening paraboloid in plane with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I have made a paraboloid in a plane:

[image]

[image]

I would like to control the shape of the top half of the paraboloid (diameter and steepness to the plane), where the paraboloid becomes a sphere and the gap in the plane closes, just like the grey line in this figure:

[image]
[Reference figure](https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1000204)

The movement is similar to blowing a bubble. Is it possible to model this with geometry nodes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/

Comment: Tnx for your reply. I've been considering using metaballs, but first I have a plane as base object and not a sphere. Second, GN gives me more control and options than particles.

Comment: @quellenform ... any idea? :)

Answer (score 2):

Since no one, here is something ...
But no control and you don't need Geometry nodes for such thing at all ...

[image]

[image]

A trick here here is ...

- **Solidify** modifier > *Thickness* **0.1**
- **Remesh** modifier > *Voxel Size* **0.08**